# VSCode not showing success alert

Tags: apex, vs-code

I clicked on "Show Only in Status Bar" by mistake.
Now when I successfully deploy Salesforce apex code in VSCode, I only get the first alert to show the deployment is running. But the second alert that pops up to show "successfully ran" is no longer showing.
Where can I find the setting to enable this again?

See screen shots

[image]

[image: Success alert]

[image: json settings file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line didn't help much:

```
"salesforcedx-vscode-core.show-cli-success-msg": true
```

So I followed these steps:

```
1. Completely remove all VSCode settings in my machine
2. Unistall VSCode
3. Restart my machine
4. Download and re-install VSCode
```

For the first step I followed these links:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603103/how-to-completely-uninstall-vscode-on-mac
and
https://medium.com/@jimkang/complete-uninstall-remove-vscode-mac-5e48bef3bdec
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding (or setting to true if it's already there)

```
"salesforcedx-vscode-core.show-cli-success-msg": true
```

to your settings.json file.

Comment: Hi Wes. I  tried your suggestion but there was no difference. I get the first alert (as per screenshot 1), but I don't get the second alert (screenshot 2). Please my see edited question.

Comment: @DevzTory when you click on "Show only in status bar" it sets the setting above to false in your settings.json file. See if that setting is already in your file and if so, set it to true. If it's not there or you can't get it to work, please post your entire settings.json file here.

Comment: Hi Wes, I have added a screenshot of my json settings file.

Answer (score 1):

1: open setting
2: search for 'success'
3: make sure "salesforcedx-vscode-core.show-cli-success-msg": true
4: close the setting tab (important step)
5: try running cli now

[image]